# TYPO3 7.1 felogin templatefile does not work via TypoScript

Tags: templates, authentication, typo3, typoscript

I'm working with the new `TYPO3 7.1` and the sysext. `felogin`.
Normally, with TYPO3 4.x-6.x I've made sth. like that:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
    storagePid = 20
    templateFile = fileadmin/templates/ext/Felogin.html
}
```

But at my new project with TYPO3 7.1 it doesn't work like that. I cannot use a storragePid or my TemplateFile via typoscript.

I don't know why? I always have to use the flexform at my content element "fe_login". Have anyone an idea?

Comment: Just when move typoscript from my EXT:custom_theme based on FLUID direct to TYPO3 Root Page TypoScript filed - i get changes. But when it included static (from my extensions) - it not work

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this into Typoscrint constants:

```
styles.content.loginform.templateFile = fileadmin/.../Felogin.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Your typoscript is without any errors and I am sure it is in the setup section of your template.

The official statement is:
You can either configure all options through the Flexform or through TypoScript. The Flexform configuration always takes precedence before the TypoScript settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Typo3 7.6.2 and I'm having the same problem. Dirks answer inspired me to move my typoscript

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
    templateFile = fileadmin/.../FrontendLogin.html
}
```

from constant part to the setup part and it work for me. Give it a try =)

Answer (score 0):

I guess i find where is problem. I added my TS as "Include static (from extensions)" from my custom extension. But all TYPO3 EXT included after this by default and override them. Ok then we can change order of Static Templates include [image]
Cool. Now my style override TYPO3 system one.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 7.6.11:

The template file for the felogin extension has major changes which make former template files unusable.
Use the default template setup.

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
 templateFile = EXT:felogin/Resources/Private/Templates/FrontendLogin.html
}
```

or simply comment our your template file setup.

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {

 # templateFile = fileadmin/mylogintemplate.html

}
```

Your login must work now. Do not continue if your login is still failing. Then it is another issue.

The you make a change in your template file. 
Add the `data-rsa-encryption=""` part as you see it in the file EXT:felogin/Resources/Private/Templates/FrontendLogin.html.

```
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" value="" data-rsa-encryption="" />
```

After that you can try out your former template file setup again.

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {

  templateFile = fileadmin/mylogintemplate.html

}
```